# How to get to "All Categories" in Microsoft Outlook with one click?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, label

I am using Microsoft Outlook for Microsoft 365 MSO and I would like to get to "All Categories" pop up screen with 1 click or a keyboard shortcut.

By default, to get to this screen the user needs to right-click the message, select "Categorize" menu option, then "All Categories" option.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: You can't; `All Categories` isn't an option for the `Set Quick Click`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try customizing the ribbon and add the "All Categories" button to your ribbon like below, so that you can use it directly:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back.

Comment: How is everything going now? Have you got your issue fixed? If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.